# Three loss functions in a Tensorflow GAN

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I've been following a guide on [O'Reilly](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/generative-adversarial-networks-for-beginners) and when it comes to their training and loss functions I'm rather perplexed.

```
d_loss_real = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(Dx,tf.ones_like(Dx)))
d_loss_fake =tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(Dg,tf.zeros_like(Dg)))

g_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(Dg, tf.ones_like(Dg)))
```

This feels like the d_loss_real and d_loss_fake should be added into a single variable and that is what should be minimized like so:

```
d_loss = d_loss_real + d_loss_fake

d_trainer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0003).minimize(d_loss, var_list=d_vars)
```

However the guide specifies three training functions rather than two, one for d_loss_real, d_loss_fake and g_loss.

```
# Train the discriminator
d_trainer_fake = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0003).minimize(d_loss_fake, 
var_list=d_vars)
d_trainer_real = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0003).minimize(d_loss_real, 
var_list=d_vars)
# Train the generator
g_trainer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(g_loss, var_list=g_vars)
```

Am I right in feeling that this is wrong, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You just need two optimizer at all, one for generator and one for discriminator network:

1) discriminator_trainer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0003).minimize(d_loss, 
var_list=d_vars)

2)generator_trainer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0003).minimize(g_loss, 
var_list=g_vars)

-Use gradient descent optimizer in your generator network for better result.